# Remove an element from Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, mailto

I have a loader between my pages.
The script works when you click on any link.
But I don't want this action in a EMAIL LINK (mailto).
How Can I avoid to do this script for the mail links ?

```
var speed = 'speed'; 

$(window).load(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut(speed, function() {
        $('a[href], button[href]').click(function(event) {
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            if (url.indexOf('#') == 0 || url.indexOf('javascript:') == 0) return;
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".loader").fadeIn(speed, function() {
                window.location = url;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: A button doesn't really have a `href` attribute? You should show us what an "email link" looks like!

Comment: Adding `|| url.indexOf('mailto:') == 0` to your existing list of exceptions (line 7) doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:not` selector or the `not()` method to exclude elements, but you have to do it on the current selection, as in `$('a[href]:not([href^="mailto:"])')` or `$('a[href], button[href]').not('[href^="mailto:"]')`, the version posted by Kristoffer won't work.

```
$(function() {
    var speed = 'slow'; 

    $(".loader").fadeOut(speed, function() {
        $('a[href]:not([href^="mailto:"])').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var url = $(this).attr('href');

            if (url.indexOf('#') !== 0 && url.indexOf('javascript:') !== 0) {

                $(".loader").fadeIn(speed, function() {
                    window.location = url;
                });
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `:not()` selector and the `[name^="value"]` (Attribute Starts With) selector.

```
$('a[href], button[href], a:not([href^=mailto])').click(function(event) {
    ...
});
```